# Название «Птичье молоко» для конфет и тортов

Tags: этимология

Почему популярный рецепт торта и конфет называется «Птичье молоко»? Как это связано с пернатыми? Насколько мне известно, не существует млекопитающих птиц, а значит название вымышленное.

Comment: проминусовал за то, что вопрос задан по поводу того, что находится в один клик и, к тому же , имеет к русскому языку косвенное отношение.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если говорить об этимологии, то существуют версии что выражение "Птичье молоко" заимствовано из древнегреческих источников:

> Как поговорка, означающая нечто редкое и драгоценное, оно приводится Аристофаном, Афенеем, Страбоном, Лукианом и др. По словам Стробона, поэты, прославлявшие плодородие острова Самоса, говорили, что на нем есть, по пословице, даже и "птичье молоко" (И.Е. Тимошенко. Литературные источники трехсот русских пословиц и поговорок. – Киев, 1897, с. 52-53).

Это выражение обозначает "нечто неслыханное", "невозможное", "предел, вершина всех желаний" и входит в такие пословицы как:

> Все есть у богатого, опричь птичьего молока
>   В Москве все найдешь, кроме птичьего молока

Встречается это выражение и в литературе:

> У меня в Москве целая усадьба на Полявине была, и дом каменный, и сад, и заведения всякие, ягоды, фрукты — все свое. Только птичьего молока не было.
>   *Салтыков. Пошехонская старина.*
>
> Я ведь ей не перечу ни в чем, птичья молока пожелает, и молока птичья достану, птицу такую сам сделаю, коли нет такой птицы!
>   *Достоевский. Хозяйка.*

Интересно что есть еще и торт "Птичье молоко", рецепт которого был создан в московском ресторане "Прага" под руководством Владимира Гуральника. Ресторан выпускал их по 600 штук в день. [Википедия пишет](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE_%28%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%29):

> Этого москвичам и гостям столицы катастрофически не хватало: в 80-е за тортом выстраивались такие очереди, что их приходилось разворачивать, чтобы люди не перекрывали движение между проспектом Калинина (ныне Новый Арбат) и Арбатом.

Считается что название этого торта возникло из-за того что его было очень трудно "достать" (вначале он назывался «[суфлейным тортом](http://supercook.ru/za-24-02.html)»).

Answer (score 8):

На самом деле некоторые птицы (голуби, фламинго, некоторые виды пингвинов) [выделяют](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/31551190) в своём зобу питательную жидкость, которой кормят птенцов, она называется "голубиное молоко" и напоминает жидкий творог.

Название же этих конфет [возникло](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptasie_mleczko) в Польше, где компания "E. Wedel" начала их производить с 1936 года под названием "Ptasie mleczko" («Птичье молоко»). Название значит "то, что достать невозможно", является идиомой и имеет аналоги в других языках. В СССР эти конфеты начали производить с 1967 года.